# Cgoban3 for offline use

Tags: java, icedtea

The software Cgoban3 client is a program to play the 
[game of Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28game%29)
online on the KGS server: http://www.gokgs.com/index.jsp

In order to download the Cgoban3 client one first has to get the file `cgoban.jlnp` from their download section. 
With `IcedTea` installed the double click on the downloaded file works fine: `IcedTea` starts, downloads the rest of the software and starts the client. It is then possible to connect to the server and start a game.

The problem is that this will not work if the computer is not connected to the internet. But I would like to do so (for example manipulating sgf files when offline, or reviewing a game).

How do I start Cgoban3 when not connected to the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you are running Ubuntu and want to play go on KGS, i.e. online, it is probably best to follow their advice and run

   > javaws http://files.gokgs.com/javaBin/cgoban.jnlp

   from a command line. `IcedTea` (or whatever) will download the client and run it automatically.
2. To run the program `Cgoban3` offline you can download the `.jar`-archive of the program with the command:

   > wget files.gokgs.com/javaBin/cgoban.jar

   This will save the file `cgoban.jar` in the working directory. 
   You will then be able to run `Cgoban3` offline with

   > java -jar cgoban.jar

   The sound may not be working then, which is a Java problem, but let's not get into that now. 
   The sound and other bugs (?) are the reason why I personally still use method 1 to play online.

Enjoy  your  go!

Comment: @user413671 method 1 don't work anymore: error Caused by: net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Application Error: Cannot grant permissions to unsigned jars. Application requested security permissions, but jars are not signed.